# Angular2 - How to UTF-8 encode within components

Tags: angular

I've added `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the main index.html file and it encodes correctly special characters (like é,ç or à) that are typed within that file without using ascii encoding like `&eacute;`.

However, component templates seem to be loosing the encoding of special characters that are not typed in ascii.

I'm not really stucked since there is the ascii workaround but I'm curious of the logic that seem to prevent character encoding within component templates.

Comment: It should work (I just tested in a Plunker).  If you add é,ç or à to index.html, do you see those characters?  If not, it is probably a config issue with your server.  I don't think this is an Angular2 issue.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the quick reply. Yes I see the é,ç and à characters in the index file. They do not display correctly however within a <my-component></my-component> for example.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, here's the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1lTpEy80tBtaSFDst3LM?p=preview  Is there anything different about your code?

Comment: Thanks again for directing my investigation. The problem was in my gulp process when creating dist folder files. I've added gulp-utf8-convert to the piping to make the /dist html files properly encoded.

Comment: I've got a similar issue with the Angular-CLI - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3061

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Mark's comments and plunker, the problem does not happen within the original dev directory.

The character encoding problem arrived when "gulping" html files to a /dist directory.

The solution in my case was to use gulp-utf8-convert https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-utf8-convert

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var utf8Convert = require('gulp-utf8-convert');

gulp.task('copy-html', function() {
return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(utf8Convert())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem but with Webpack

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code in terminal to change all .ts files encoding to UTF-8.

```
for file in ./**/*.ts; do  iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-16 "$file" -o "${file}"; done
for file in ./**/*.ts; do  iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 "$file" -o "${file}"; done
```